# How can I find the error in the following SQL query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I keep getting the following error on line 5:

```
Error at line 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  trg_videorental_up  
AFTER UPDATE OF DETAIL_RETURNDATE ON DETAILRENTAL 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
      IF :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NULL THEN UPDATE VIDEO SET VID_STATUS =       'OUT' WHERE    VIDEO.VID_NUM = :NEW.VID_NUM; 
      ELSIF :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE > SYSDATE  THEN UPDATE VIDEO SET VID_STATUS = 'OUT' WHERE VIDEO.VID_NUM = :NEW.VID_NUM; 
      ELSIF:NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE ='01/01/01' THEN UPDATE VIDEO SET VID_STATUS= 'LOST' WHERE VIDEO.VID_NUM = :NEW.VID_NUM;
      ELSIF :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE <= SYSDATE THEN UPDATE VIDEO SET VID_STATUS = 'IN'  WHERE VIDEO.VID_NUM=  :NEW.VID_NUM;
      END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Well, you're missing a space before one of the colons... (Also `'01/01/01'` is not a date; that isn't causing the error, but don't rely on implicit conversions, or use 2-digit years.)

Comment: Actually, what you've posted [doesn't throw that exception](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fd22486130094ff711c1aaa34bb11f60). Maybe it's from how you're calling it?

Comment: That isn't a query, or SQL. PL/SQL is a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing to a single update with a case/when for the value... if none of your other values, just set it to its original vid_status value.  Easier to read too (IMO)

```
UPDATE VIDEO SET VID_STATUS = 
          case when :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NULL 
                 OR :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE > SYSDATE THEN 'OUT' 
               when :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE ='01/01/01' THEN 'LOST' 
               when :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE <= SYSDATE THEN 'IN'  
               else VID_STATUS end
   WHERE VIDEO.VID_NUM = :NEW.VID_NUM;
```

Put back in the ":", apparently I was incorrect on removing it.  I am not as familiar with Oracle for triggers/procedures.

Comment: When I run the querry, a dialog box appears where it says "NEW: ____ ." What should I fill there?

Comment: @SaadAhmed, Revised answer.  Looked at Oracle triggers and they don't use leading ":" before the "New" alias reference.  Try and let me know.

Comment: @APC, duly noted, put back in the ":" references which was my original post.  I am not an Oracle specialist and accept when I am incorrect.  Thanks for correction.

Comment: Thanks. It still did not work, but I am collaborating with my team. Hopefully will get it sorted out.